# How to add edit and delete buttons in django admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I want to add 2 buttons in django admin, like on this screenshot, but instead of "Deposit" and "Withdraw" there should be "Edit" and "Delete"

I found lots of answers how to add custom actions, but is there a proper way to add such buttons? All methods for them are written, it seems to me that this two buttons should be added mush more easier.

[image]
picture came from here:
https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-add-custom-action-buttons-to-django-admin-8d266f5b0d41

but I'm interested in easier solution, if such exists

Comment: Where did the example screenshot come from? Is this an existing Django app that you can link to?

Comment: @FamousJameous https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-add-custom-action-buttons-to-django-admin-8d266f5b0d41

found this here, but I'm interested in easier solution, if such exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

list_display from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) provides me to add smth for every object. So I added this in my MyModelAdmin:

```
def change_button(self, obj):
    return format_html('<a class="btn" href="/admin/my_app/my_model/{}/change/">Change</a>', obj.id)

def delete_button(self, obj):
    return format_html('<a class="btn" href="/admin/my_app/my_model/{}/delete/">Delete</a>', obj.id)

list_display = ('__str__', 'change_button', 'delete_button')
```

And now this two buttons are added. This is still not the best way I guess, but mush easier then adding any other action.